# How to quickly fail a python script if it is called from wrong interpreter?

Tags: python, jython

I have inherited a few Python scripts from someone who has left my employer. Some are meant to be run from Jython, others are not.

I'd like to add them to svn, but before I do I want to modify these files so that if a "requires Jython" file is run from python, the user gets a message like "please run with Jython" and the program exits.

(Warning: I am not very familiar with Python/Jython.)

I expect the simplest way to do this is create a file `require-jython.py` with the contents like:

```
if runtime.name !=  'jython'
  print "Please run with Jython"
  exit(1)
```

and then "include/require"? this file (again I'm not an expert. bear with me here)

Can anyone spell out the steps for me?

Comment: Why do you need the code to be run with Jython? What sorts of things break if you run it in a different interpreter?

Comment: Jython code makes calls to Java.

Comment: @nosklo. The failures can be misleading. Like a syntax error. If I know what will cause the problem, before it happens, I should do something about it and communicate the problem to the user of the script.

Comment: i am curious, why can't everything run with jython?

Comment: @bronzebeard You are right. If I could rid the universe of all non-Jython Python implementations I wouldn't have this problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that and someone (maybe even me) might accidentally try to use/run/invoke this code from a non-Jython environment and I'd like to gently remind them not to.

Comment: Just wanted to note that you *don't* want to name this file `require-jython.py`, hyphens are not valid characters in module names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have seen done is to try to import a module exclusive to a given version or implementation, and raise `ImportError` if the module does not exist.

Imagine that Jython (**and not Python**) has a module called `special`, then you add:

```
# at the top of your module:
try:
   import special
except ImportError:
   raise ImportError("this script is meant to be used with Jython")
else:
   raise
```

Notice that you make the ImportError exception more explicit, as opposed to simply raising it (and lead the user to believe that there was a problem with the module itself, as opposed to informing that the interpreter was improperly selected). I would give you a more concrete example of what module to import, but I am not at all familiar with Jython.

In other words, use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) for the module import: assume the import was made correctly but fail as soon as you cannot find the expected behaviour (this is what the `try` statement is supposed to be used for).

Another way to check the interpreter is to use the `sys` module (in Python - I don't know if Jython has it):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.subversion
('CPython', 'tags/r264', '75821M')
```

Comment: Agree, you should not test the interpreter directly, just if the modules you require are available. If you want to inform the user that he is probably using the wrong interpreter, I would prefer using a print and then re-throw the original exception just so in case the user knows what he's doing but forgot to install a module, he knows what's missing.

Comment: Jython can use java packages. So import java should be sufficient.  The special module you are looking for is _java_.

Comment: sys.subversion is missing from Jython (or the version I have). It's one of the things I briefly looked into.